# Stop sourcing a file

Tags: fish

I have deleted phpbrew and now having this error when starting up the terminal:

source: Error encountered while sourcing file “/home/machine/.phpbrew/phpbrew.fish”:
source: No such file or directory

How do I get a list of all sourced files and stop sourcing a certain file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in general to get a list of all sourced files. Such information isn't recorded in any single place, or even multiple, places that can be checked with 100% certainty you didn't overlook one. However, in this case that probably isn't necessary since it is almost certainly going to be due to a source command run from your fish config script or a script it runs. So

```
cd ~/.config/fish
grep source **.fish
grep '\. ' **.fish
```

The latter because `.` is an alias for `source`. You may not find `source phpbrew.fish` because that script may be sourced by a plugin manager like fisherman or oh-my-fish. In which case it might be loaded indirectly by the plugin manager.

Comment: It helped me in a way that I understood that I need to edit config.fish file. I removed the line with source command.